# Problems adding a layer in yocto

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I am very new to yocto and am trying to learn how to use it. I followed the steps in the mega-manual section [section 5.1.9](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.3.2/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#creating-a-general-layer-using-the-yocto-layer-script). I ran

`yocto-layer create mylayer`

and edited my bblayers.conf file to have this:

```
 BBLAYERS = ?" \
    /usr/local/src/yocto/meta \
    /usr/local/src/yocto/meta-poky \
    /usr/local/src/yocto/meta-yocto-bsp \
    /usr/local/src/yocto/meta-mylayer \
    "
```

I ran `source oe-init-build-env` and then `bitbake core-image-sato`. When the build finished, I ran `runqemu qemu86 nographics` and after logging in, ran `find / -name helloworld` since mylayer defines a recipe for building helloworld. However, the file was not found.

Shouldn't this program (helloworld) be included in the image created? What step(s) am I missing here?

meta-mylayer/conf/layer.conf:

```
# We have a conf and classes directory, add to BBPATH
BBPATH .= ":${LAYERDIR}"

# We have recipes-* directories, add to BBFILES
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb \
    ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend"

BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "mylayer"
BBFILE_PATTERN_mylayer = "^${LAYERDIR}/"
BBFILE_PRIORITY_mylayer = "6"
```

meta-mylayer/recipies-example/example/example_0.1.bb

```
#
# This file was derived from the 'Hello World!' example recipe in the
# Yocto Project Development Manual.
#

SUMMARY = "Simple helloworld application"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://helloworld.c"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
     ${CC} ${LDFLAGS} helloworld.c -o helloworld
}

do_install() {
     install -d ${D}${bindir}
     install -m 0755 helloworld ${D}${bindir}
}
```

meta-mylayer/recipes-example/example/example-0.1/helloworld.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a new layer doesn't add every recipe in the layer to every image, it  just makes those recipes available to build.

Add the packages that you want in the image using IMAGE_INSTALL in the image recipe.

This is covered in the documentation at http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#usingpoky-extend-customimage.

Comment: thank you, I did not read far enough through the manual! By the way, the IMAGE_INSTALL_append should be set to the recipe name that the script creates (with the leading space), so in my case, " example"